# comparative sentences - different / same

Tags: sentence-construction

I think when we are stating the differences between two things, we need to be clear about what is being compared to what, so there is no misunderstanding. So, when I use the word "different" or "same", I'd like to make sure what is compared to what. And I'm more comfortable when I can recognize them, because they take the same form. And here is what I've made:

## Q. What do you usually do to keep yourself healthy?

> 1.**The things** that I do to keep myself healthy is not different from **the things** that others do.
>
> 2.**What I usually do** to keep myself healthy is pretty much the same as **what others do.**
>
> 3.**I keep myself healthy** in pretty much the same way as **others do**.
>
> 4.**The way** that I keep myself healthy is pretty much the same as **the way** that others do
>
> 5.The ways of **me keeping myself healthy** and **others keeping themselves healthy** are pretty much the same.

I just go jogging or doing some weight traing as others do.

Even though I know this phrases could cause others to be confused because it's kind of wordy, I happen to stick to phrasing like this. Are these sentences not good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sentences mostly sound fine, though indeed a bit wordy. However, there is nothing wrong with having long sentences as opposed to more concise ones. It depends on your own style, but bear in mind that you want to keep your sentences pleasant to read, so avoid extremely wordy constructions where a few words would do.

That being said, here are a few corrections:

In sentence 4, you should change *the way that* to *the way in which*. Someone does something **in** a certain way, so make sure you do not omit the preposition, even in combination with a subclause.

In your sentence about jogging, *doing* should be conjugated. Your subject is *I* and your sentence consists of two main clauses that are linked with the coordinating conjunction *or*. Therefore, *do* has the same subject as *go* and should be conjugated accordingly. Here's your sentence rephrased with the subject repeated in order to clarify what I just said:

> **I** just *go* jogging or **I** *do* some weight training as others do.